# Type traits to distinguish between a const char[N] and a std::string?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, variadic-templates

How do I write a variadic template that takes both const char[N]s and std::strings as parameters, but performs a different behaviour depending on the parameter type?

So far, my variadic template looks as followed:

```
template<typename T>
void Capitalize_And_Output(T&& str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper); //<- will not compile with char*s
    std::cout << str << std::endl;  
    return;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Capitalize_And_Output(First&& str, Strings&&... rest) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper); //<- will not compile with char*s
    std::cout << str << " ";
    Capitalize_And_Output(std::forward<Strings>(rest)...);
    return;
}
```

Using "universal" references, everything is accepted into the function.
However, calling the function like this, will not work:

```
std::string hello = "hello";
std::string earth = "earth";

//fails because "planet" is a const char[N] and not a std::string
Capitalize_And_Output(hello,"planet","earth"); //outputs: "HELLO PLANET EARTH"
```

It DOES work if I do the following:

```
Capitalize_And_Output(hello,std::string("planet"),"earth"); //outputs: "HELLO PLANET EARTH"
```

But I don't want the user to be responsible for making this conversion.  How can I pass that responsibility into the template function instead?

I have been trying to make the decision using type traits, but have not been successful.
I was trying to use:

```
std::is_same<First, std::string&>::value
```

but did not know how to make the branch decision.  I do not believe this works inside of an if statement.

Maybe I need to use std::conditional somehow?
Maybe I need to solve it by creating a local variable in the template that is type auto&&?  I haven't had any success so far in the varying things I have tried.

Comment: Use `std::begin` and `std::end`. String literals are, in fact, not `char *`, and not even `const char *`. They are `const char[N]`.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to make the first parameter a `std::string` instead of a type-deduced argument and rely on the existing implicit conversions.

Comment: @chris: But that would give the end of the array (including the terminator), not the end of the string (excluding the terminator).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Never mind, I forgot that would still try to modfiy the literals.

Comment: @chris: You're right; in this case, it's probably OK. I was misreading the code, and thinking you might end up with rogue terminators in the output.

Comment: @Trevor Hickey, are you sure you want to modify the `string` arguments?  I would think that you would want to take all arguments as `const` as simply print an upper-case version of all inputs.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I suppose the function name could be misleading if it modifies the strings. However, my intention was to give a simplified version of the actual problem, and focus on the implementation only.

Comment: @TrevorHickey, Just to be really clear:  For the purpose of this question, you *do* want the original arguments to be modified, where possible?  Also: Is this an integral part of the design you want in your application, or a (intended) simplification to be used here?  Or perhaps you don't have an application in mind, and you just want a general technique to distinguish between `char[]` and `string`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, original arguments should be modified (if possible).  This is all for an intended simplification, but also a bit of experimenting for future applications.  Often times, char[] and string are thought of synonymously, and I wanted to find a way to write functions that both modify and handle the two types similarity.

Answer (score 4):

I see two issues with [Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491746/simple)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639804/1137388):

(1) It fails to compile this test case

```
std::string hello = "hello";
const std::string earth = "earth";
Capitalize_And_Output(hello, "planet", earth);
```

because `earth` is a `const std::string` and there's no overload which can take this call. (Try it!)

(2) It fails to compile for types (other than `const char*` and alikes) that are convertible to `std::string`, for instance,

```
struct beautiful {
    operator std::string() const {
        return "beautiful";
    }
};

Capitalize_And_Output(hello, beautiful{}, "planet", earth);
```

The following implementations solves these issues:

**New solution**: My old solution (below) works but it's not efficient for `char*`, `char[N]`. In addition, it's complicate and uses some overload resolution trickery to avoid ambiguities. This one is simpler and more efficient.

```
void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(const char* str) {
    while (char c = toupper(*str++))
        std::cout << c;
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::string& str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), toupper);
    std::cout << str;
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(const std::string& str) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(str.data());
}

template<typename First>
void Capitalize_And_Output(First&& str) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::forward<First>(str));
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Capitalize_And_Output(First&& str, Strings&&... rest) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::forward<First>(str));
    std::cout << ' ';
    Capitalize_And_Output(std::forward<Strings>(rest)...);
}
```

Because I don't use `std::transform` (except for the second overload), it doesn't need to know the size of the string in advance. Therefore, for a `char*` there's no need to call `std::strlen` (as in other solutions).

A small detail to notice is that this implementation only prints space between words. (It doesn't print one after the last word.)

**Old solution**:

```
void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::string& str, int) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
    std::cout << str << ' ';
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::string str, long) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(str, 0);
}

void Capitalize_And_Output() {
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Capitalize_And_Output(First&& str, Strings&&... rest) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::forward<First>(str), 0);
    Capitalize_And_Output(std::forward<Strings>(rest)...);
}
```

I guess the two `Capitalize_And_Output_impl` overloads deserve explanations.

Firstly disconsider the second argument (`int`/`long`). The first overload can take non `const` lvalues which are capitalized on exit (as requested by Trevor Hickney in a comment to Simple's solution ).

The second oveload is meant to take everything else i.e., rvalues and `const` lvalues. The idea is to copy the argument to an lvalue which is then passed to the first overload. This function could naturally be implemented in this way (still disconsidering the second argument):

```
void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(const std::string& str) {
    std::string tmp(str);
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(tmp);
}
```

This work as required. However, a famous [article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) by Dave Abrahams explains that when you take an argument by reference to `const` and copies it inside your function (as above), it's better to take the argument by value (because in some circunstances the compiler might avoid the copy). In summary, this implementation is preferable:

```
void Capitalize_And_Output_impl(std::string str) {
    Capitalize_And_Output_impl(str);
}
```

Unfortunately, as for the first overload, calls to `Capitalize_And_Output_impl` on lvalues can also be directed to this overload. This yields an ambiguity which the compiler complains about. That's why we need the second argument.

The first overload takes an `int` and the second takes a `long`. Therefore, passing the literal `0`, which is an `int`, makes the first overload preferable over the second but only when the ambiguity arises. In the other cases, i.e., when the first argument is an rvalue or `const` lvalue the first overload cannot be used whereas the second one can after the literal `0` is promoted to `long`.

Two final remarks. (1) if you want to avoid the recursive call in `Capitalize_And_Output` (I guess this is just a question of taste), then you can use the same trickery as in Simple's solution (through `unpack`) and (2) I don't see the need to pass the lambda wrapping `::toupper` as in Simple's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need type traits for this:

```
char safer_toupper(unsigned char const c)
{
    return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c));
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_Impl(std::string& str)
{
    auto const first = str.begin();
    std::transform(first, str.end(), first, safer_toupper);
    std::cout << str;
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_Impl(std::string const& str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(),
                   std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                   safer_toupper);
}

void Capitalize_And_Output_Impl(char const* const str)
{
    std::transform(str, str + std::strlen(str),
                   std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                   safer_toupper);
}

template<typename... Strings>
void Capitalize_And_Output(Strings&&... rest)
{
    int const unpack[]{0, (Capitalize_And_Output_Impl(rest),
                           std::cout << ' ', 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(unpack);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to take the std::strings by reference, so that the lvalues passed in remain changed after the function call? I would like the objects passed in to remain uppercased after the function has ended (unless of course they were a string literal...)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. What does static_cast<void>(unpack); do? I commented it out, and could not see a difference in performance anywhere. Oh, I think it is suppose to prohibit a zero parameter function call, but for some reason, it does not.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: The cast to `void` at the end just avoids a compiler warning (e.g. GCC with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) saying that `unpack` is defined/initialized but never used. It doesn't produce any code.

Comment: This is less efficient than it could be, it creates unnecessary temporary strings when handling const char* strings and literal strings and does unnecessary strlen calculations with literal strings.

Comment: @mattnewport I've improved the code but I don't like the approach you took with `char` arrays to avoid `strlen` calls. Just because something is in a `char` array doesn't mean all of the array is a string.

Comment: That's a valid point and I hadn't considered that possibility. I'd argue that in this case it would be user error to pass such a char array to this function but I can see why your version might be preferred.

Comment: I didn't actually notice before that the original function modified non const strings in place. That's a much worse problem with this function IMO but it is what the original poster seems to want.

Answer (score 1):

This version does no unnecessary copying of arguments, introduces no unnecessary temporary strings and avoids calling `strlen()` for literal strings whose length is known at compile time.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename I> void CapitalizeAndOutputImpl(I first, I last) {
    std::string t;
    std::transform(first, last, std::back_inserter(t), std::toupper);
    std::cout << t << " ";
}

template<typename T>
struct CapitalizeAndOutputHelper {
    void operator()(const T& s) {
        CapitalizeAndOutputImpl(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct CapitalizeAndOutputHelper<T*> {
    void operator()(const T* s) {
        CapitalizeAndOutputImpl(s, s + std::strlen(s));
    }
};

template<typename T> void CapitalizeAndOutput(T&& s) {
    CapitalizeAndOutputHelper<std::remove_reference<T>::type>()(s);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest> void CapitalizeAndOutput(First&& first, Rest&&... rest) {
    CapitalizeAndOutputHelper<std::remove_reference<First>::type>()(first);
    CapitalizeAndOutput(rest...);
}

int main() {
    std::string hello{ "string hello" };
    const std::string world{ "const string world" };
    char arrHello[] = "char[] hello";
    const char vHelloInit[] = "char* hello";
    std::vector<char> vHello(std::begin(vHelloInit), std::end(vHelloInit));
    const char* cworld = "const char* world";
    CapitalizeAndOutput(hello, world, arrHello, "literal world", vHello.data(), cworld);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest is to have two overloads:

```
void do_stuff() {}
template<class...Ts>
void do_stuff(std::string s, Ts&&... ts);
```

and using your existing body for the second.

We get perfect forwarding, then just before your mutate and output, we copy.

If you want the mutate to propogate out, you are probably wrong.  If you insist, @Cassio's approach looks decent.